# Check if element contains any of multiple classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to check to see if an element contains ANY one of multiple classes in plain JavaScript. Is there a way to do the following with less code / more concisely?

```
let element = document.querySelector('.element');
if( element.classList.contains('class-1') || element.classList.contains('class-2') || element.classList.contains('class-3') {
  // do something
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: An array of classes could work with the method `some`. Also, a nice method `matches` [exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).

Comment: Let us take two arrays `arr1 = [1, 2, 3];` and `arr2 = [1, 4, 5];`. Consider `arr1` to be the `classList` and `arr2` to be an array of the class-names (ie `['class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3']`). Now, to check if any element in `arr1` matches any element in `arr2`, please try: `if (arr1.some(x => arr2.some(y => x === y))) { // do something };`

Comment: Thank you. I got this to work after converting the classList to an array but the accepted answer was a little more concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `if(element.matches(selector)) //returns true or false` where selector would be `selector = ".class-1, .class-2, .class-3"` in your case. This works with any CSS Selector. If you want every class to be present, you would need `selector = ".class-1.class-2.class-3` for example. You can learn more about CSS-Selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp